# How to delete multilines pattern with sed ?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to delete multiline isc dhcpd config with one commandline.

I'm trying to do it with sed

[My regex looks good](http://regexr.com/3e7m2)

but I'm not able to use in sed command

`sed '/subnet 10.5.154.*{((.|\n)*?)}((.|\n)*?)}/d' dhcpd.conf`

What I'm missing ?

Comment: JavaScript regex flavor is different from sed regex flavor. If regexr shows a match, sed does not have to.

Comment: thanks for the info. I didn't know there was several flavors of regex between languages, only notion of basic, normal or extended. regex set  I'm network engineer and in some routers is present basic regex set. Didn't understand the downvote - quite a nice start here at stackoverflow.

Comment: In POSIX, `.` matches any character, including a newline char. Also, POSIX regex flavor does not support lazy quantifiers.

Comment: Actually, sed is not the best tool to use for multiline string manipulation, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `sed` *is* well suited for multiline string manipulation. That post you linked is subjective - imo. However, I agree that `sed` is not the right tool in this case since this case is about matching `{}` recursively - even if the OP did not explicitly stated that. I suggest to use [`omshell`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/omshell) for that rather than a regex even if Perl compatible regular expression could perform the recursive matching of `{}`

Comment: @hek2mgl: I do not say one cannot use `sed` at all, just it might seem too cumbersome for a person coming from ES5 regex. A perl solution would be easier to understand for OP in my opinion.

Comment: thanks guys. still don't understand the down votes. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed works line by line and uses by default the BRE (Basic Regular Expression) syntax, But what you can do is to define a range of lines with two patterns (using the fact that blocks end with an empty line, or using the indentation since the closing } starts the line) and to use the delete command.

if there's an empty line after a block:

```
sed '/^subnet 10\.5\.154\.0/,/^$/d' file
```

or using the closing bracket at the start of the line:

```
sed '/^subnet 10\.5\.154\.0/,/^}/d' file
```